# Get GPS data from MOV (quicktime) video file

Tags: gps, quicktime, .mov

Please help to get GPS track with time from .mov file.
The file is fom car camera and consists GPS data because its viewer shows car position.
What is right way to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say if you're looking for a programming solution to parse the file and read the GPS metadata yourself, or whether you're looking for a tool that will display the data.

It also depends very much on the specific camera that recorded the file as they embed data in different formats. If you have an iPhone, for example, it records GPS data in a mdta metadata atom with key "com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709", but other formats exist too, especially if you mean real time varying GPS data embedded in each frame, rather in the header for the movie as a whole.

Tools that will read such data from the movie header include [ExifTool](https://www.sno.phy.queensu.ca/~phil/exiftool/) and [CatDV](http://www.squarebox.com) (though the latter is a commercial product).

Answer (score 2):

I found that `ffprobe` from the ffmpeg project was able to extract the `com.apple.quicktime.location.ISO6709` tag.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue, I used the [ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/). It's a great tool for extracting metadata from a wide variety of file types. Even if your file type is not currently supported by the application, you can write to the author Phil Harvey and he will finalize his application within a reasonable time.